# How to use xpath expression and get required data in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, xpath

I am trying to get some details from http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter site, I requested the site and got response as html document. Now I want to parse this html and get some data by using xpath. I am using python 2.7.

I have tried with some code but could not help it out.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser.HTMLParser.unescape()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
item = dict()
item['category'] = 'Movie'
item['title'] = tree.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
print item
```

And also tried with..

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
response = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter')
response_body = response.text
root = ET.fromstring(response_body)
print root.findall(".//a")
item = dict()
item['title'] = response_body.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
print item
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by lxml library.
First you need to install lxml by "pip install lxml" command in windows
then follow the below code:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
anchor_url = tree.xpath('your xpath expression goes here')
print anchor_url
```